# How to partition a digraph for later parallel computation?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, parallel-computing, process-scheduling

I have a directed graph where all the nodes represent some task that needs to be computed. I need to compute the order of these tasks and also detect any cycles. Running Tarjan's algorithm on the graph gives me both.

To the problem:

I was wondering if there exists a good way to make use of parallelization. For instance, node A goes to node B and C. We can then compute task B and [C,F] in parallel. After that we can compute tasks [E,I] and [D,G] in parallel as well.

[image]

What kind of algorithm could detect which subsets of the tasks that can be computed in parallel?

I was thinking about the following procedure:

- Select a start node $n_1$ and a finish node $n_f$.
- Compute all possible paths $n_1 \rightarrow n_f$.
- If there is only one path then this whole branch can be assigned to be computed by one processor.
- Then I mark all nodes on this path.
- Now i select another finishing node and repeat until I have marked all nodes.
- Should there exist more than one path $n_1 \rightarrow n_f$ I reduce the path length by one and instead compute all paths $n_1 \rightarrow n_{f-1}$ where $n_{f-1}$ is a parent to $n_{f}$

Comment: "Compute all possible paths $n_1→n_f$. " -- since there may be super-exponentially many of those, that may not be advisable.

Comment: I read the linked answer with the approach of grouping nodes of same depth in sets, but I'm not sure how this works. For instance, in this digraph http://oi65.tinypic.com/2uz7bf9.jpg we have that nodes K, L and J have the same path length (depth?) and so they can be grouped in a set. But J depend on K and L so it can't be executed at in parallel with K and L. Have I misunderstood something about the meaning of "depth"?

Comment: Follow the definition of the $S_i$ I give. You'll find that $J \not\in S_3$; "depth" does not mean the same as tree depth here, but is a notion that respects the happens-before relationship, exactly as you require.